Domain of convergence
Domain of Convergence of series
$$\Sigma_{n=1}^\infty x^n(1-x)^n \frac{n4^n}{3^n}$$
My attempt:
The radius of convergence is given by
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \lvert\frac{n4^n}{3^n} 
\lvert ^{1/n}=\frac{1}{R}$$
$$|x(x-1)| \le 3/4$$
$$-3\le 4x^2-4 \le 3$$
$$4x^2-4x+3 \ge 0$$ This has complex roots so we can ignore the same.
$$4x^2-4x-3\le 0 $$
$$\implies (2x-3)(2x+1)\le 0$$
Then $x\le3/2$ and $x\ge-1/2$ or
$x\ge3/2$ and $x\le-1/2$ which is not possible
Then, the interval of Convergence is
$$x\in (-1/2,3/2)$$
Is this correct? If not correct, please help how to proceed.

Two pointers: Be sure to handle the absolute value with care - it's not the case that $|x(x-1)| = x^2-x$. So you may need to split up into cases on the value of $x$. Second, note that you cannot have $x\le -1/2$ and $x\ge3/2$ at the same time, so your second case yields no actual solutions (in the same vein, your last formula should have $\cap$, not $\cup$ - do you see why?)

Thank you for pointing out mistakes. I have edited the same. Hope I understood correctly what you were pointing out.

Oh, I think my first point caused some confusion due to how I wrote it. What I meant is that $x(1-x)$ is equal to $\pm(x-x^2)$ depending on the the value of $x$. You need to consider both cases (it may be that the end result is the same).

Ok I got your point. It can be done other way like, $-3 \le (4x^2-4x) \le 3$. Right hand inequality is same as one done. Other inequality gives complex roots, so we can ignore that case as we are dealing in real line. Thank you for clarifying.

This is a partial solution:
This series converges on $[0,1]$. The convergence at the endpoints is obvious.
Next, notice that $f(x)=x(1-x)$ achieves its maximum at $x=\frac{1}{2}$.
That is $$|f(x)|\leq f(\frac{1}{2})=\frac{1}{4},\quad 0<x<1.$$
Then
$$ x^n(1-x)^n \frac{n4^n}{3^n}\leq \frac{1}{4^{n}} \frac{n4^n}{3^n}=\frac{n}{3^n}$$
which is a convergent series of positive numbers by, say, the ratio test.
Remarks:
(1) This is not the optimal (largest) domain of convergence.
(2) We have the necessary condition
$$|x||1-x|<\frac{3}{4}.\qquad (1)$$
If $x$ does not satisfy the inequality $(1)$ the series diverges because
$\sum_{n\geq 1} n$ is divergent. So, the set $\{x\in \mathbb{R}:|x||1-x|< \frac{3}{4}\}$ strictly contains the domain of convergence. One can easily find $\delta>0$ such that the series diverges on $\{x\in \mathbb{R}:|x||1-x|> \frac{3}{4}-\delta\}$, since $\sum_{n\geq 1} \frac{1}{n}$ diverges.
Lastly, a warning:
(3) I won't treat the series in question as a power series. It is a "growing" sum of power series.

Thank you for answering. I have few doubts on your remarks may be it is basic but want to clarify. Remark (1) is it possible to find optimal domain of Convergence if so how? Any hints. (2) How you related the series with $\Sigma_{n\ge 1}n$ and $\Sigma_{n\ge 1}1/n$.

Can you plot $|x||1-x|$ ? You may plot it using some software like Mathematica. Any way,  $f(0)=f(1)=0$. and we have seen that as long as $|f(x)|\leq 1/2$ the series is convergent.  You will notice that outside the interval $[0,1]$ the function is monotone. Precisely, there exists $b>1$ such that $0<f(x)\leq 1/2$ for all $x\in [1,b]$ and there exists $a<0$ such that $0<f(x)\leq 1/2$ for all $x\in [a,0]$. So your series is absolutely convergent on $[a,b]$. (2). Solve the inequalities starting from the values of $x$..
